# Fibonacci sequence in system of equations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Can we write/solve the fibonacci sequence in a linear system of equations, for a given number of terms?

I know we can define the recursive definition using matrices but what i am interested in is calculating a number of terms by defining AX = B and then solving for X ( = [x_1, x_2, x_3, ...] .). ..... But what are A and B ?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the fibonacci sequence as $f_0 = f_1 = 1$ and $f_{n+1} = f_n+f_{n-1}$, then you can come up with this linear system for the first $5$ fibonacci numbers:

$$f_0 = 1$$

$$f_1 = 1$$

$$f_0+f_1-f_2 = 0$$

$$f_1+f_2-f_3 = 0$$

$$f_2+f_3-f_4 = 0$$

This can be written in matrix form as $$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0 \\  1&1&-1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&-1&0 \\ 0&0&1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}}_{A} \ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} f_0 \\ f_1 \\ f_2 \\ f_3 \\ f_4\end{bmatrix}}_{X} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}}_{B}$$

You can use the same method for the first $N$ fibonacci numbers for any positive integer $N$.

Note: This is by no means the most efficient way to compute the first $N$ fibonacci numbers, but it is in the form that OP requested.